# Airflow schedular doesnt pick the DAG on specific schedule_interval config( 0 8 * * 5)

Tags: cron, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I want to add schedule(Every Friday at 8:00 AM) to the DAG. Below is my config for the DAG:

DAG CONFIG:

```
args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(20),
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email': [failure_email],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': True,
}

dag = DAG(dag_id='dag_airflow_delete_logs_less_than_40_days',
          default_args=args, 
          schedule_interval='0 8 * * 5',
          max_active_runs=1)
```

After adding the schedule to DAG, airflow didn't pick up the dag on Friday 8:00 AM UTC. I removed '5' from the crontab schedule and configured as '0 8 * * *' it worked fine for every day.

I also tried different ways to schedule interval using crontab format, still no luck:

```
(0 8 * * 5)
(0 8 * * FRI)
```

I don't understand why it's not working when I specify the day in the interval? Please let me know your thoughts. Thanks in advance!

Note: I used below websites to check the crontab configs .
1) https://crontab.guru/
2) http://corntab.com

Attached Screenshot for the DAG Runs: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=5x4x3d&s=9#.W-RSjLpFyFQ

Comment: Can you post the screenshot of DAG runs so that we know which interval it is running at if it doesn't run every Friday? The `schedule_interval` expression looks fine to me.

Comment: Thanks @kaxil for your reply. I have attached the screenshot for your reference. Also FYI this is newly created DAG, we ran this dag manually for few days and decided to schedule it. Please note in the screenshot you will find schedule as 00 8 * * 5 crontab schedule which is equivalent to above mentioned schedules.